# Magento : Allow URL as parameter

Tags: magento

I am integrating Bazaarvoice in Magento for Ratings and Reviews.
My issue is Bazaarvoice is redirecting to My site with some additional parameter in URL and it turns in to 404 error. I have contacted Bazaaevoice and they told me that Magento may not allow url as a parameter.

```
www.mysite.com/bazaarvoice?pid=4801-05E&bvdisplaycode=7529-en_us&bvappcode=rr&bvproductid=4801-05E&bvpage=http://abcd.ugc.bazaarvoice.com%2Fbvstaging%2F7529-en_us%2F4801-05E%2Fsubmitreview.htm%3Fformat%3Dembedded%26campaignid%3DBV_RATING_SUMMARY_ZERO_REVIEWS%26sessionparams%3D__BVSESSIONPARAMS__%26&bvcontenttype=REVIEW_SUBMISSION&bvauthenticateuser=false
```

IS there any solution that i can make the Magento to allow URL as a parameter.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Magento do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think the issue is the parameter because this work

```
http://demo.magentocommerce.com/?pid=4801-05E&bvdisplaycode=7529-en_us&bvappcode=rr&bvproductid=4801-05E&bvpage=http://abcd.ugc.bazaarvoice.com%2Fbvstaging%2F7529-en_us%2F4801-05E%2Fsubmitreview.htm%3Fformat%3Dembedded%26campaignid%3DBV_RATING_SUMMARY_ZERO_REVIEWS%26sessionparams%3D__BVSESSIONPARAMS__%26&bvcontenttype=REVIEW_SUBMISSION&bvauthenticateuser=false
```

I think the issue maybe because you dont have this controller in your magento site

> bazaarvoice

Does this url work or do you get a 404?

> www.mysite.com/bazaarvoice

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply

opps it was my fault, i did not mention the exact url ,just because i want to keep the url secret. we have hosted it on our staging server and its url seems like
Site url = http://alpha.abcd.org/mysite
and http://alpha.abcd.org/mysite/bazaarvoice is working fine. and showing one missing loading image.

Comment: It seems like there is some server related issue rather than Magento and bazaarvoice.